# mysql php select table timestamp in range

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I want to Select Wallpapers in range  using timestamp
Like this

```
SELECT * FROM wallpaper WHERE timestamp = '1221507428' to '1221761585' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5
```

How to Fix time 
using timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [BETWEEN ... AND](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) construct.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   wallpaper 
WHERE  `timestamp` BETWEEN '1221507428' AND '1221761585' 
ORDER  BY Rand() 
LIMIT  5
```

Also you can use comparison operators

```
SELECT * 
FROM   wallpaper 
WHERE  `timestamp` >= '1221507428' 
        OR `timestamp` <= '1221761585' 
ORDER  BY Rand() 
LIMIT  5
```

Comment: in this case is the RAND() is fast ? or will be slow in Time OR Whats is good for RAND() for 8000 wallpapers database?

Comment: @HAS It should only be counted for the results, that is for the five rows max.

Comment: can i use like this  ?

'SELECT * 
FROM   wallpaper 
WHERE  `timestamp` >= '2012-01-01' 
        OR `timestamp` <= '2011-01-01' 
ORDER  BY Rand() 
LIMIT  5'

Comment: @HAS yes if the type of `timestamp` column is `date` or `datetime`

Comment: timestamp >= '2012-01-01' OR timestamp <= '2011-01-01'  this is work in this ?

Comment: `timestamp >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-01-01') OR timestamp <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2011-01-01')` or `FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp) >= '2012-01-01' OR FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp) <= '2011-01-01'`

Answer (score 2):

Use `between`, here is the full query:

```
SELECT * FROM wallpaper WHERE `wallpaperid` between '1221507428' and '1221761585' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5
```

[More info](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)

Comment: You forgot to write the field's name before `between`.
`SELECT * FROM wallpaper WHERE timestamp between '1221507428' and '1221761585' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5`

Comment: And What is good  if in date range going and the wallpaper select in range and the new adding wallpaper will go on!

Comment: In this case the RAND() will faster or Slow ?

Comment: As long as there is `LIMIT 5` RAND() will not affect result.